# How to update parent's variable from a child component

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently in a situation where I need to update a value outside of the current component that i'm using. I tried passing the set function from useState, but react returns an error: "Cannot update a component (`Parent`) while rendering a different component (`Child`)."

What I have so far:

Parent Component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Child } from './child';

export const Parent = () => {
  const [x, setX] = useState<number>(0);


  return(
    <>
      <Child function={setX} />
   </>
  )
}
```

Child Component

```
import React from 'react';

interface ChildProps {
  function: Function
}

export const Child = (props: ChildProps) => {

  props.function(5);

  return(
    <>
    </>
  )
}
```

Since probably I can't do that with useState, I would like to know what I can do, to perform this task.

Comment: Try wrapping `props.function(5)` into `React.useEffect(() => {}, [])`. Otherwise, your parent component will always re-rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can call a function passed via props.
Try to call the function when the component is rendered using the `useEffect` hook.

!!ALSO!! - don't use the keyword `function` for the prop. Use another word, `fn` `setX`....

Child component:

```js
import React from 'react';

interface ChildProps {
  fn: Function
}

export const Child = (props: ChildProps) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    props.fn(5);    
  }, []);


  return(
    <>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I totally forgot to try useEffect. Thanks for the advice on the keyword "Function", I'm not using it on the real problem, I just wrote it while writing a smaller version of the current code to post it here, haha.